# How do I view the xml in firefox in a simpler way?

Tags: firefox, xml

When I view the following URL:

http://upmedia.plymouth.ac.uk/Rss.aspx?CategoryId=20

I doesnt show anything in firefox. However when I view

http://upmedia.plymouth.ac.uk/itunesuRssfeed.aspx?CategoryId=20

I can see loads of xml represented in a semi graphical form.

How do I just see the raw xml on these feeds? Preferably with some formatting so that all of the nodes escape to new lines etc.

I would prefer to use firefox or a plugin rather than install another bit of software.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to view the raw XML just occasionally instead of every time, right-clicking the page and choosing "View Page Source" seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [this](http://www.miuaiga.com/index.cfm/2009/8/27/View-XML-directly-in-Firefox-without-the-annoying-add-to-reader-screen):

> 1. In FF, go to Tools > Options in the top menu
> 2. Select the Applications tab
> 3. Scroll down to "Web Feed" (how annoying ... not 'xml', not 'rss', but 'web feed'? really? )
> 4. Change the Web Feed 'action' to "Preview in Firefox" (mine said "Use Google" before changing)
> 5. Click the 'ok' button and go to any .xml file url to see all the wonderful XML , sans reader-prompt annoyance !

Comment: Probably it's "Web feed" because it applies to both RSS & Atom feeds.

Comment: Builtin XML/RSS/Atom viewer [was removed in FF 64](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/live-bookmarks?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Live+Bookmarks)